# Silverlight MVVM framework with navigation

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, navigation

We're just starting up a new (our first) Silverlight project where we want to make a back office silverlight application using MVVM. Our application will need navigation through some kind of menu UI.

I've been poking around the web finding various frameworks (Galasoft MVVM Light Toolkit / Silverlight.FX / Prism) to help with building a MVVM application but i find it hard to single out which one suits our needs the best.

Does anyone have any experience/tips on which one to pick for a larger application with many Views and navigation between them.

Also, is a navigation Application the best way to get a "framed" application (with navigation inside the frame) or is there a better way?

Comment: As a sidenote i think the guy who took over the project decided to go with Caliburn (http://caliburn.codeplex.com/)

Comment: An answer below references [this article](https://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2009/11/dynamic-module-loading-with-silverlight.html). It may be deleted, so I will preserve it here.

Answer (score 4):

I'll throw in a vote for Prism/Composite Application Guidance...mainly because I've used it in a number of "for work" projects.

The modularity stuff is great - you basically code up individual projects as if they were miniature applications in their own right, and you rely on the region management paradigm to composite your multiple "modules" into one cohesive app.

It does get a bit annoying as the module count gets high, although you don't **have** to make each module its own project...

Comment: +1 for mentioning the annoying part. I find it very annoying that Prism is aimed to serve many assemblies. I just need the navigation, but want to keep all the modules together, not as standalones.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [this article](http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2009/11/dynamic-module-loading-with-silverlight.html)  written by Jeremy Likness.  He is using Prism and Navigation framework and its a good article to get you going with.  Its also not hard to take the sample he provides and apply some MVVM principles to it.

Comment: +1 Great article thanks for the link.  Really helped me understand internals Navigation Application as well as Prism.

Comment: This appears to be a link-only answer, and so probably is not substantive enough for a Stack Overflow answer. I will ask the Review Queue to take a look. I have preserved the link as a comment in case this is deleted.